# Primefaces Facesmessage disappears after hiding dialog

Tags: primefaces

I have a page with a dialog like below. I want to show the user an error message in case the info already exists on the same dialog.  This part works fine.

However, if all goes well the dialog should close AND the "success" message should show on the calling page (e.g. in the JSF template p:messages).
I can't get this to work, the message disappears. I tried several options including the remote command.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogNewMailingList" header="New Mailing List"
        modal="true" resizable="false" widgetVar="dialogList">

        <h:form id="newMailingListForm">

            <p:messages id="listMessages" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Name :" for="listName"
                    style="font-weight: bold;" />
                <p:inputText id="listName"
                    value="#{mailingListsEditController.newMailingList.name}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill in a Name" size="50" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Description :" for="description"
                    style="font-weight: bold;" />
                <p:inputText id="description"
                    value="#{mailingListsEditController.newMailingList.description}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please fill in a Description"
                    size="50" maxlength="100" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:remoteCommand name="updateMessages" update=":messages" />

            <p:commandButton
                action="#{mailingListsEditController.saveMailingList}"
                update="@form,:mailinglists:selectMailingList"
                oncomplete="listSaveRequest(xhr, status, args); updateMessages()"
                value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
            <p:commandButton onclick="dialogList.hide()" value="Cancel"
                immediate="true" icon="ui-icon-cancel" />

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
    function listSaveRequest(xhr, status, args) {  
        if(args.validationFailed) {  
            jQuery('#dialogNewMailingList').effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
        } else {
            //alert('List created successfully.')
            dialogList.hide(); 
        }  
    }  
    </script>
```

The bean method save()

```
public void saveMailingList() {

    log.debug("Saving new MailingList :" + newMailingList.getName());

    emailService.save(newMailingList);

    // show message to the user
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Save Mailing List",
            new FacesMessage("Mailing List successfully created."));
}
```

I feel I am close to the solution :)

Thanks for any help,
Coen

Answer (score 0):

The `p:messages` element should be placed outside of the `p:dialog`. By closing the dialog all child elements get hidden, including the messages.